# Jquery Sortable - Disable onclick="" while sorting

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-ui-sortable

is it possible to disable onclick="" while sorting?

I Have a working example here http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/59/

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do it with a flag variable as per @nigative , you can do the following with the start and stop methods:

```
$("#lop").sortable({
  revert: '100',
    placeholder: 'auo',
    start: function(event, ui) {
       ui.item[0].oldclick = ui.item[0].onclick;
       ui.item[0].onclick = null;     
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
       ui.item[0].onclick = ui.item[0].oldclick;
    }
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me because as I dropped the item the onclick was still being detected.  I was able to work around this by using setTimeout when restoring the onclick function: `setTimeout(function(){ ui.item[0].onclick = ui.item[0].oldclick }, 500);`

Answer (score 3):

you can use `start` and `stop` options:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   start: function(event, ui) { ... },
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Just create a flag and set to true when sorting started and to false when the sorting is over and in your onclick function check the flag first:

```
var isBeingSorted = false

$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   start: function(event, ui) { isBeingSorted = true; },
   stop: function(event, ui) { isBeingSorted = false; }
});

function printAlert(message){
   if(!isBeingSorted)
       alert(message);
}
```

And of course your onclicks should look like `onclick="printAlert('sdfsdf')"`

For more options look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable)

Comment: Thank you for the fast anwser!